# Дайте пожалуйста пример вызова fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

JavaScript
Пытаюсь получить простой JSON через fetch
Данные в файле .json:
{ "id" : 1, "text": "Отзыв1","approved": false}

Проблема в том что fetch пролетает нигде не задерживаясь и я не могу заполнить переменную data1 данными.
Потом (через некоторое время) идут обратные запросы к блокам then и данные заполняются.

Подскажите пожалуйста - как дождаться окончания работы fetch?
Т.е. я хочу положить запрошенные данные в переменную data1

```
    console.log('fetch');
    var data1;
    fetch('fetch2.json')
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type'));
            console.log(response.status);

            return response.json();

            // if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            //     return response.json();
            // } else {
            //     return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
            // }
        })
        .then(function(data_json) {
            console.log(data_json.text);
            data1=data_json;
        })
    ;
        // .catch(err => console.error(err));
    console.log('111111111111111');
    console.log(data1);
```

Comment: Прочитал ответ - но все равно не понял.

Основная идея-создается Promice:
function getResult(N) {  return new Promise

Использование результата осуществляется через вызов then
getResult(42).then(function (result) {
  someDiv.textContent = result;
});

Тогда получается fetch (возвращает Promice) в том виде как я ее написал должна выдавать значение - а она не выдает и проваливается дальше.

Почему ?

Comment: задумайтесь над словом "асинхронность". Помедитируйте.

Comment: Попробуйте так:
async function getjson() {
const response = await fetch('fetch2.json');
const json = await response.json(); 
console.log(json);
}
getjson()

Comment: Dedotmoroz, спасибо за подсказку!

Но не помогло.

  var json1;
        async function getjson() {
            const response = await fetch('fetch2.json');
            json1= await response.json();
            console.log(json1.id);
        }

        getjson();
        console.log('111111111111111');
        console.log(json1.text);

Comment: Вот вывод с консоли: 111111111111111
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
  (anonymous function) 
1

Comment: т.е. несмотря на наличие await - ожидание не происходит и код спокойно выполняется дальше